# If I develop a media player for mobile or desktop do I have to pay for a license if my player is able to read MP3 files?

Tags: licensing, android, mobile, copyright, iphone

I know MP3 is not open source format but proprietary and I found this website http://mp3licensing.com/help/developers.html that states that you need a license for basically everything that uses MP3.

But the thing is that even hardware devices that support MP3s need license. So if a mobile phone is able to play MP3s already do I need an extra license for my application that would be launched, let's say, on Appstore on Google Play Store?

Answer (score 5):

I read quite a few forum topics and mailing list ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OTySJlWT_UE)), the general answer was that if you are using the Android SDK, and you do not have an MP3 encoder/decoder in your application, then you don't need a license for your app. The MP3 license for playing is already provided by the device manufacturer.

<s>Also, basically everywhere else than the USA, MP3 patents are no longer in effect, so you don't need to pay royalties at all. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3), [list of patents](http://www.tunequest.org/a-big-list-of-mp3-patents/20070226/))</s> As of now, all MP3 patents have expired:

> On April 23, 2017, Technicolor's mp3 licensing program for certain mp3 related patents and software of Technicolor and Fraunhofer IIS has been terminated.

Source: https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/prod/audiocodec/audiocodecs/mp3.html (Your original link now redirects here too!)

Comment: "basically everywhere else than the USA, MP3 patents are no longer in effect" is there any source for this ? Thanks.

Comment: Added two links in the answer.

Comment: koszi for the links

Comment: "In the United States, the technology will be substantially patent-free on 31 December 2017 (see below). The majority of MP3 patents expired in the US between 2007 and 2015." Oooh, nice.